# powershell: how to retrieve the computer name in dns format

Tags: powershell, dns, wmi

I want to retrieve the current computer name as an [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) on a windows 7 machine e.g. computername.companyname.local.  How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return it as a string:

```
gwmi Win32_ComputerSystem| %{$_.DNSHostName + '.' + $_.Domain}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using framework .NET this is working on my domain :

```
([system.net.dns]::GetHostByName("localhost")).hostname
```

You can also find the information here under (but you have to rebuild it):

```
[System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not running on a machine with a real domain, so I can't be 100% sure, but I think that this could work for you:

```
get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.DNSHostName} | select @{n="FQDN";e={$_.DNSHostName + "." + $_.DNSDomain } } | format-table
```

For my Thinkpad laptop, this returns something like this:

```
FQDN
----
t500.home
```